# Google StyleのPython Docstringで、「非推奨」はどのように表せばよいでしょうか？

Tags: python, sphinx

## 背景

PythonのdocstringをGoogle Styleで記載しています。
docstringの内容は、sphinxのautodoc機能でHTMLドキュメントに反映しています。

## 質問

非推奨のメソッドは、docstringにどのような内容を記載すればよいでしょうか？
JavaDocの`@Deprecated`のようなタグを期待しています。

[Example Google Style Python Docstring](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html)を読みましたが、deprecatedに関する記述は見つかりませんでした。

## 補足

今は、以下のようなコードを書いています。

```py
    def get_hoge(self):
        """【非推奨】hogeを取得

        DEPRECATED

        """
        warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
        pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

現時点では、**Google Style Guide**はDeprecatedである関数・メソッドについての記載方法を提供していません。このため、回答としては「そのような方法はないので独自の形式で表現してください」となります。

[styleguide/pyguide.md at gh-pages · google/styleguide](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/9c6b371f419b1dd33c338846e3e7c1ce7304baff/pyguide.md)

一方、**reStructuredText**にはdeprecatedを表すディクレティブが存在します。もしSphinxでドキュメントを生成する場合、これが利用できます。

> ```
> .. deprecated:: 3.1
>    Use :func:`spam` instead.
> ```
>
> [ディレクティブ — Sphinx 3.0.0+/9a795cb0 ドキュメント](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/ja/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-deprecated)